# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException In hibernate OneToOne Relation?

Tags: java, hibernate

```
package com.mallesh.hibernate;

import java.sql.Date;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration;

public class AppTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     System.out.println("Hello Come Here please");
     Session session=new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory().openSession();//exception occur in this line
     session.beginTransaction();
     EmployeeDetails employeeDetails=new EmployeeDetails("Kalloli Street","Gokak","Karnataka","India");
     Employee employee=new Employee("MAllesh","Kalloli",new Date(121212),"8792127613");
     employee.setEmployeeDetails(employeeDetails);
     employeeDetails.setEmployee(employee);
     session.save(employee);
     session.beginTransaction().commit();
     session.close();

    }

}
```

Comment: It would be nice to see how Employee and EmployeeDetails are annotated. Your code seems right, so the problem must be in the orm mapping.

Comment: Add your full stack trace in order to find where the error occured

Comment: can you post your mapping configuration?

Answer (score 0):

```
employee.setEmployeeDetails(employeeDetails);  (1)
employeeDetails.setEmployee(employee);         (2)
```

If Employee table has FK of EmployeeDetails you must set,

```
employee.setEmployeeDetails(employeeDetails);
```

so as I think line(2) must remove.